# STM32CubeMX/STM32L0 UART Transmit unknown symbols

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, uart, communication

I am trying to connect UART communication with STM32L053C8-Discovery. But the problem is on terminal I get unknown symbols.

My Setup on CubeMX

[image: STM32CubeMX]
[image: UART]

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
uint8_t tx_buff[]={1};
uint8_t rx_buff[10];

  while (1)
  {
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5);
    HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart1,tx_buff,sizeof(tx_buff));// Sending in DMA mode
    HAL_Delay(1000);
}
```

To RX,TX pins I connected FT232RL FTDI module.

[image]

[image]

With Arduino it works but with STM32 in terminal I get only symbols. Maybe someone could explain me how to correctly set the format?

[image]

Also there is a full code of *main.c:*
https://pastebin.com/kST92XWZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Baud rate mismatch.**

Baud rate is set to 9600 baud on the screenshots, but it's 9800 in the linked code.

```
huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9800;
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. But I'm getting the same result with 9600. 

https://pastebin.com/qAFpiuy9

Comment: `tx_buff[]={1};` is not a printable character code. What should your terminal program do with it? Try transmitting a string.

Comment: Thank you for your replay! I've downloaded STM32Cube MCU Package for STM32L0 series from [link](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubel0.html). There was an example of UART communication. I will analyse it. 

Have a good day!